# time condition is not working in sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am tring to compare with current time and rocords exist in DB .

My condition is like record exist in data base time should be less than current time .but its not working .

below is code and snap.

sch_time is the field name

```html
SELECT 
    rs.week_day, 
    rs.reportsch_tid, 
    rs.sch_time, 
    rs.reportsch_id, 
    rl.report_lid 
FROM 
    report_schedule rs 
    LEFT JOIN report_log rl ON(
        rs.reportsch_id = rl.reportsch_id
    ) 
WHERE 
    sch_time < '11:39:46' 
    AND (
        case WHEN(
            (rs.reportsch_tid = 2) 
            OR (
                rs.reportsch_tid = 3 
                AND rs.week_day = 2
            )
        ) then DATE(schedule_time)= '0000-00-00 00:00:00' else DATE(schedule_time)= '2017-09-19' END
    )
```

[image]

Comment: you need to use timestamp() or date() there.

Comment: timestamp(sch_time) is it  ?

Comment: noafter giving time stamp also its not working.

Answer (score 0):

sch_time and  '11:39:46' are being compared as strings and likely the cause of the problem. hard to tell without the table definition.  Should be using an timestamp or time field for the field definition.  failing that you'll need to convert them to integers to do a proper conversion/evaluation.

Comment: sch_time is time type